# NSURLErrorDomain error -1012 from personnal server

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0

Here is the error I get:

```
HTTP. GET Sync error from http:/ **** local: 8000/v1/apps / **** / devices / **** / Service lastUpdate = 1399652941: Error Domain = NSURLErrorDomain Code = -1012 "The operation couldn't be (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.) completed. "UserInfo = 0x178079340 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://****.local8000/v1/apps/****/devices/****/service?lastUpdate=1399652941, NSUnderlyingError 0x170253bf0 = "The operation couldn't be completed (error -1012 kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork.)." NSErrorFailingURLKey = http:// **** local. 8000/v1/apps / **** / devices / *** * / service? lastUpdate = 1399652941}
```

I do not understand why I have this error, especially as the network call up my server does not. I ask nothing to the user. 
I do everything automatically and the user ID is generated and unique.

Someone to help me?

EDIT:
This is a GET method in which I try to enter my server resources where OAuth2 is implemented .
In my application I have the headers or the token that was provided by the server is specified .

```
/ / Perform request asynchronously or not
    if ( self.async ) {
        self.connection = [ NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest : request delegate : self ] ;
    Else { }
        NSURLResponse * response = nil ;
        [ self.data appendData : [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest : request
                                                    returningResponse : & response
                                                                error: error] ] ;

        if ( [ self.data length] > 0 && * error == nil) {
            NSLog ( @"HTTP : Sync GET response from% @ :% @" ,
                   url,
                   [[[ NSString alloc] initWithBytes : [ self.data bytes ]
                                             length: [ self.data length]
                                           encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ] autorelease ] ) ;
            return self.data ;
        Else { }
            NSLog (@"HTTP : GET Sync error from% @ :% @" , url, * error ) ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you paste some code and explain the entire situation?

Comment: I still have the same problem on other services ... Any ideas?